# react-native NavigatorIOS rightButton can't click

Tags: ios, react-native

react-native NavigatorIOS rightButton can't click.

```
onRightButtonPress: function(){

     this.refs.nav.push({
       title: 'From Right',
       component: DetailViewController,
     })
  },
```

Nothing happen when I click the `rightButton`

```
 render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS ref="nav"

        initialRoute={{
          component: HomeScene,       
          title: 'NavigatorIOS Demo..', 
          rightButtonTitle: 'MORE!', 
          onRightButtonPress: this.onRightButtonPress, 

          leftButtonTitle:'leftItem',
        }}>
      </NavigatorIOS>
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind() the method to 'this'.
Or instead, use the => notation to define the method.